# Environment variable set by putenv() are not present while running a shell script using shell_exec() | PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I have a PHP script in which I am setting a environment variable using `putenv()` and then I am calling a shell script using `shell_exec()` in this PHP script.
In shell script I am trying to use that environment variable.

**My PHP script is like:**

```html
<?php
...
...
putenv("USERHOME=/home/user/mnt");
...
...
shell_exec("sudo ./script.sh arg1 arg2");
...
...
?>
```

**My shell script is like:**

```
#!/bin/sh
...
...
echo "USER HOME=" $USERHOME
...
<---Another use of $USERHOME----->
...
exit $?
```

I am using Xampp for my application and PHP version is 5.3.8.

Previously it was working fine on fedora core 3. 
But recently I moved my application to CentOS 7 and now it is not working. 
On CentOS 7, I am getting NULL value of USERHOME variable.

Comment: are you able to get the output if the `shell_exec` command is run this way ? `shell_exec("USERHOME=/home/user/mnt ./script.sh arg1 arg2")`

Comment: @anurupr No. I tried 
`shell_exec("USERHOME=/home/user/mnt ./script.sh arg1 arg2")` and
`shell_exec("export USERHOME=/home/user/mnt ./script.sh arg1 arg2")`.
But same behavior.

Comment: are you storing the output of the `shell_exec` command in a variable? because the browser doesn't print it by default. e.g. `$output = shell_exec("./script.sh arg1 arg2"); echo $output;`

Comment: @anurupr Yes. But I am not printing it on browser instead I am writing it in a log file. 
My PHP script is able to run the shell script but getting NULL value of the variable USERHOME set by putenv().

Comment: can you show the output of the log file?

Comment: @anurupr output in the log file is like following
...some output of other commands in script....... **USER HOME=** ......... some output of other commands in script

Comment: works for me with PHP 7.0.22 on ubuntu. can you try with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see if there is any warning?

Comment: @isalgueiro I am using **xampp** for my application and **PHP version is 5.3.8**. 
Tried with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` , no warning observed.

Comment: OK, in that PHP version there are safe mode directives that limit what environment vars you can set with putenv. You've to edit `safe_mode_protected_env_vars`. I'm writting this in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and debugging, I am able to get the correct value of environment variable in my shell script, which is set by putenv() in my PHP script.

First of all, I am new to PHP and here also. And I missed some things in question while posting it. Now I have edited my question and provided all the required details and script contents correctly.

**Root Cause and Resolution:**

In my PHP script I was running the shell script through shell_exec() and was using **sudo** in the command
`shell_exec("sudo ./script.sh arg1 arg2");`
This sudo is the main problem here.

Removing it and calling the script simply `shell_exec("./script.sh arg1 arg2");` did the trick.

The shell_exec() call with sudo was working fine on Fedora Core 3.
But when I moved my application to CentOS 7, it stopped working. After removing sudo from the command it is running as expected on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP < 5.4 there's a safe_mode directive that limits what environment variables you can write with `putenv`. Edit your php.ini file and remove `USERHOME` from the `safe_mode_protected_env_vars` setting.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-protected-env-vars

Comment: Thanks for your guidance and link. I am new in PHP and didn't knew about this. 
But my problem is different. The variable USERHOME is user defined environment variable. Thus it is not present in php.ini file, also `safe_mode_protected_env_vars` setting is not applicable on this.  

However after some research and debugging I am able to find out the culprit. I am writing my solution in answer.
Thanks :)